# Custom color setting (for entity.name.function.js) from settings.json overridden by latest VSCode update

Tags: visual-studio-code

Latest update of VS Code changed color of at least one element I had customized for `js` via `settings.json` (`entity.name.function.js`). The color is changed for keywords like `resolve`, `then`, `reject`, `bind`, but not all function names(!). Other of my custom colors seem to remain unaffected. I did not change anything in the `settings.json`.

When I open the `Developer: Inspect Editor Tokens and Scope` option and select the elements of the code with incorrect color I see:

foreground  <s>entity.name.function.js { "foreground": "#9493DA" }</s>

which suggests the custom color definition is recognized by VS Code, but not applied for some reason.

What can be the reason and how to make VS Code apply the desired styling?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the update changed classification of some keywords from `support.function.js` to `support.function`. After adding the latter to `settings.json` color was applied properly.